# How to use Regex in Google Spreadsheets to mass replace a combination of codes in a column

Tags: regex, replace, find, spreadsheet

I have a column in a google spreadsheet that is 1000 rows deep in just one column. The row has a number of 2 digit codes from a list of 30.

Heres a sample of 5 rows to what I want their output to be.
Where mc = "moon", mf = "mother", etc

```
mc mf md -> moon, mother, mad,
mc ff -> moon, floof,
mc ff la in -> moon, floof, lamb, internet,
mf md -> mother, mad,
gr mf -> grandma, mother,
```

I would like to expand each row, replacing each with the expanded code.

I am using the 'search using regular expressions' in my spreadsheet, and I have these two:

find:

```
 (mc)|(mf)|(md)
```

replace:

```
 (?1moon,)(?2mother,)(?3mad,)
```

So far, it replaces mc mf md with 
    (?1moon,)(?2mother,)(?3mad,)(?1moon,)(?2mother,)(?3mad,)(?1moon,)(?2mother,)(?3mad,)

I understand it as, "find mc or mf or md, and replace it with this string. I want to replace all instances of mc with moon, replace all instances of mf with mother, and find all instances of md as mad.

All of the 30 2-digit codes are unique, so they should never accidently replace eachother.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Google Spreadsheets do not support conditional replacement patterns, only Boost regex does. Use Notepad++ if you need that functionality, or just replace one by one, starting with the longest pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way to achieve what you want with one regex in *Google Spreadsheets*** as their RE2 regex engine does not support *conditional replacement patterns*. Boost regex does, and if you copy/paste the columns to Notepad++, you will see it is working fine, here is the result of the `mc mf md` substitution:

[image]

In Google Spreadsheets, you can write a script or a function that would just utilize chained replace method. *Make sure* you replace *longer strings first*.